# Is the order of iteration in bash for loop guaranteed?

Tags: linux, bash, glob

Let's say I have a for loop in bash which looks like this:

```
for i in $MYDIR/*.jar
do
    # do something with files
done
```

Is the order of iteration guaranteed, i.e. will the loop always process files in same order? If it is guaranteed, is the order alphabetical?

Comment: I believe this applies: http://serverfault.com/a/122743/1239

Comment: BTW, this isn't a question about for loops in general, it's a question about globs. `for i in 9 5 3; do echo "$i"; done` would operate in that order.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  It's not the loop that expands your * .  The shell will first expand your *.jar into a list of files, and then the loop will iterate over that list of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [bash man page](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> Pathname Expansion
>
> After word splitting, unless the -f option has been set, bash scans
>   each word for the characters *, ?, and [. If one of these characters
>   appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an
>   alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see
>   Pattern Matching below).

So, the files will be processed in **alphabetical order** (which depends on your locale, see comments) due to globbing expansion rules.

Comment: Only ASCII order if your locale is C. "alphabetically sorted" doesn't universally mean ASCII.

Comment: ...for instance, some locales have a collation order of AaBbCc... and for others it's ABC...abc...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I edited my answer